# Math on result of data pulled from two independent non intersecting tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Goal is using the table field information below, perform different calculations(sum on table1 field1, count on table2 field2) on one field from each table, then divide the results of each separate calculation to get "result" (see Equation below).

The problem is my SQL statement always only pulls counts Employees common with both tables. For example, for 340 count of employees Table2 with the training hours from table1 over date range = 18, the "result" should be 18/340=.05, but for my SQL statement, it only sees 3 of 340 employees so it gives and answer of 18/3 = 6. I want count of all employees in table2 regardless of date range and table1, then independently sum hours in table1 over the date range, then divide these two independent results(hrs/count) to get final "result".

The table/field information:

```
table1 = Training_Action_SPPAL (sub table of All_Actions table)
table1 field1 = double1
table1 field2 = date1  (date1 range filter = 10/01/2014 to 09/30/2015)


table2 = Employee
table2 field1 = name
```

Equation:

```
sum(double1)/count(name) = "result" over date range of date1
```

Example data single SQL statements run independently:

```
sum(double1) = 420.5    
count(name) = 380    
result = 1.1  (hand calculated, but SQL below resulted in 2.7)
```

The SQL that worked but gave wrong result:

```
SELECT (SUM(a.double1)) / (COUNT(name))
FROM all_actions a, employee
WHERE a.category='Training_Action_SPPAL'
  AND a.date1 BETWEEN '10/01/2014' AND '09/30/2015'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would separate getting the values into two queries like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT Sum(double1) FROM all_actions 
  WHERE category='Training_Action_SPPAL' AND date1 between '10/01/2014' and '09/30/2015') / 
(SELECT Count(*) FROM Employee) AS Result
```